# Daterangepicker date defaults to zero in CakePHP

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, daterangepicker

I'm developing a small app with CakePHP and I need to save a `startdate` and an `enddate` for an event. I went with the [Bootstrap Daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) to let users visually input the dates.

In my `add.ctp` view I have two fields:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <?php echo $this->Form->input('start', array(
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'type' => 'text', 
    'id' => 'start',
    'name' => 'start',
    'data-mask')); ?>
</div><!-- .form-group -->
<div class="form-group">
  <?php echo $this->Form->input('end', array(
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'type' => 'text', 
    'id' => 'end', 
    'name' => 'end',
    'data-mask')); ?>
</div>
```

And the Javascript that controls the inputs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('input[name="start"]').daterangepicker({
      timePicker24Hour: true,
      singleDatePicker: true,
      timePicker: false,
      timePickerIncrement: 30,
      locale: {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
      }
    });
    $('input[name="end"]').daterangepicker({
      timePicker24Hour: true,
      singleDatePicker: true,
      timePicker: false,
      timePickerIncrement: 30,
      locale: {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The picker works just fine, it updates the field values properly, but when I attempt to save the form, the start field gets written to the database as follows:

> start 0000-00-00 00:00:00
>   end (null)

The form data for the start and end fields saves properly if I'm reverting to the default configuration of the fields.

Any clue as to where I'm failing would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is the field type in database ?

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you working with? Have you tried to debug the `$this->request->data` content in the controller before saving? Are you transforming the value of the input field in your controller or are you using any validation (and in case of CakePHP3 application) rules?

Comment: @PradeepSingh, the fields are datetime. I was passing strings to the database. Figured this out by debugging the request data, as advised by Oops D'oh. And I'm looking at a race because both your comments pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: does that solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was passing text to a datetime field and the save operation failed. In order to fix this I had to convert the strings to the proper type by processing it in the `beforeSave()` function of the model.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

    if (!empty($this->data['Task']['start']) && !empty($this->data['Task']['end'])) {

        $this->data['Task']['start'] = $this->dateFormatBeforeSave($this->data['Task']['start']);
        $this->data['Task']['end'] = $this->dateFormatBeforeSave($this->data['Task']['end']);
        }

        return true;
    }


public function dateFormatBeforeSave($dateString) {
    return date('Y-m-d h:m:s', strtotime($dateString));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$correctdate = date("Y-m-d j:h:m",strtotime($yourdate));
```

It's not a great peace of code, but it should help to go further in the right direction.
We take this string and make a timestamp out of it. Then we change it to a proper datetime value.